# Generate image for human checking

Tags: api

Some website when we login failure for multiple time(like hotmail, gmail), it will pop a picture, and ask us to key in the word in the picture.

May I know is there any `API or code` online to generate such a picture on the fly for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Captcha` is the current terminology, you see the detailed in the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha

Here is an `open source` version: http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/